# Resizing plots in plotly (R)

Tags: r, plotly

Sorry if this question has already been answered but I can't find a solution.

I have a data frame which is imported from a .csv file. It has four columns. I want to plot a 3d scatter plot of the first two columns against the last column using Plotly.

The problem is that for some reason, the scatter plot does not automatically resize its axes to fit the plot space. So in this case I end up with a tall thin plot. The weird thing is that if I do an example with some random numbers, I don't get this problem.

Can anyone help me to get my scatter plot to fit to the window?

My data can be found at https://www.dropbox.com/s/ojwrezjker33x2b/Data.csv?dl=0

Basically I want to do:

```
library(plotly)
X<-read.csv("Data.csv")
plot_ly(x=X[,1],y=X[,2],z=X[,4],type='scatter3d',mode='markers')
```

And this results in a tall and thin scatter plot (sorry can't post an image cos I am new to the site).

I would like this to be a well-proportioned scatter plot that fits the window.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default setting for `aspectmode` is `'auto'` and Plotly will try to keep the relative axis lenghts equal.

If you set [`aspectmode='cube'`](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-scene-aspectmode) you should get a plot with identical absolute axes lengths.

```
plot_ly(x=X[,1],y=X[,2],z=X[,4],type='scatter3d',mode='markers') %>% 
    layout(scene=list(aspectmode='cube'))
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks very much!